# How can I program a proper login form and stay logged in with php class session?

Tags: php, html, debugging, session, cookies

how to submit cookies so that I am logged in always?

"I am looking to create the sign in process with secure forms, and create a cookie/session that allows me to log in once.

However, when I go to my log in screen, the forms are not registering and the cookie is not being saved correctly

My forms

```
<div class ="col-md-4 col-md-offset-5">
<h4 class="bg-danger"> <?php echo $the_message; ?></h4>
    <div class="container-main"></div>
<form action="" method="post">

    <div class ="form-group">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" value="<?php echo htmlentities($username); ?>">
    </div>

    <div class=form-group">
        <label for="username">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" value="<?php echo htmlentities($password); ?>">
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary">


    </div>



    </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

My class called session (functions)

```
class Session {

    private $signed_in = false;

    public $user_id;

    public $message;

    public $tester = false;

    function __construct() {

        session_start();
        $this->check_the_login();
        $this->check_message();
        $this->visitor_count();

    }

    public function message($msg=""){

        if(!empty($msg)){

            $_SESSION['message'] = $msg;

        } else{

            return $this->message;
        }

    }


    public function check_message(){

        if(isset($_SESSION['message'])){
            $this->message = $_SESSION['message'];
            unset($_SESSION['message']);
        } else{

            $this->message = "";
        }
    }
    /**
     * @return mixed boolean T/F if user has signed in
     */
    public function is_signed_in(){
        return $this->signed_in;
    }


    /**
     * @return mixed boolean T/F if admin has signed in
     */
    public function is_tester_signed_in(){
        return $this->tester;
    }

    /**
     * @param $user object user that is browsing the session
     */
    public function login($user){
        if ($user){
            $this->user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user->id;
            if ($this->user_id == '43' ) {

                $this->signed_in = true;


            } else {
                $this->tester = true;
            }

        }

    }

    public function logout() {

        unset($_SESSION['user_id']);
        unset($this->user->user_id);
        $this->signed_in = false;

    }
    private function check_the_login(){

        if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){

            $this->user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
            if ($this->user_id == '43' ) {
                session_set_cookie_params(time() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 20));
                $this->signed_in = true;

            } else {
                $this->tester = true;
            }


        } else{

            //check that it's still 0;
//            $this->signed_in = false;
//            $this->tester = false;
//            $this->user_id = 0;
//            unset($this->user_id);
            if ($this->user_id == '43' ) {
                $this->signed_in = false;

            } else {
                $this->tester = false;
            }


        }
    }

    /**
     * @return int the number of session views WTF?
     */
    public function visitor_count() {
        if(isset($_SESSION['count'])){
            return $this->count = $_SESSION['count']++;
        } else {
            return $_SESSION['count'] = 1;
        }
    }
}


$session = new Session();

?>
```

Functions for the form:

```
<?php
$the_message = "Welcome";

if($session->is_signed_in()){
    echo $session->is_signed_in();

    //redirect("index.php");
}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $username = trim($_POST['username']);


    $password = trim($_POST['password']);



    //METHOD 1to check database user if exists, otherwise sign UP BUDDY!


    $user_found = User::verify_user($username, $password);
    //METHOD 2 Check the database.
    if($user_found){

        $session->login($user_found);

        redirect("index.php");

    } else {
        $the_message = "Your password or username are incorrect";

    }


    //The page is loaded and $user_FOUND is not found


    } else {
    $username = "";
    $password ="";

}
?>
```

Comment: You're not actually authenticating the user anywhere. Your workflow should be 1) check if `$_SESSION['user_id']` exists. If so, the user is logged in. 2) If you are using persistent sessions, check if that cookie is set and verify the value against the database. If it matches, the user is logged in. 3) Verify username and password against the values stored in the database. If it matches, the user is logged in. If 2) or 3) pass, set the `$_SESSION['user_id']`.

Comment: I updated with the form functions included, my first guess was to decide when to set the cookie, because the session starts arbitrarily, and could set it there, so it always exists. 
Can you refer to a specific function to set these parameters?

Comment: That's a lot of code to go through. I suggest you try to narrow it down to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Show what you mean by "the forms are not registering and the cookie is not being saved correctly" and how you determined this.